# How to make conditional comparisions between a value with Date Differemce (DATETIME - DATETIME)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Motivation:  I want to check users who made the action within 5 days since his first login.

Here is the sample data:

```
ID    DATE_LOGIN    DATE_ACTION 
1     2019-01-01    2019-01-03
2     2019-01-05    2019-01-06
3     2019-01-19    2019-01-25
```

Here is the expected result

```
ID    DATE_LOGIN    DATE_ACTION
1     2019-01-01    2019-01-03
2     2019-01-05    2019-01-06
```

This my try so far:

```
df['date_diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_ACTION']) - pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_LOGIN'])
```

`

```
ID    DATE_LOGIN    DATE_ACTION     date_diff
1     2019-01-01    2019-01-03        2 days
2     2019-01-05    2019-01-06        1 days
3     2019-01-10    2019-01-25       15 days
```

`

```
df[df['date_diff'] <= 5]
```

However, I get this errors

> TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want compre timedeltas with integer, so raised error. So you can convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) for numeric, so possible compare by `number`:

```
df[df['date_diff'].dt.days <= 5]
```

Or you can compare with [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```
df[df['date_diff'] <= pd.Timedelta(5, unit='d')]
```